# Matplotlib prints white as gray in pdf format, but not in png format

Tags: python, image, pdf

I am trying to write an image file to PDF format, using something like:

```
plt.imsave('output.pdf', myImg)
```

My image (myImg) is in a 3D array RGB format of uint8 values from 0 to 255. In my specific application all of the pixels are either black or white (0, 0, 0) or (255, 255, 255). But when I use plt.imsave to save the pdf, the blacks stay black but the whites turn middle-gray. The weirdest part is that when I use the exact same line of code but write a png file:

```
plt.imsave('output.png', myImg)
```

The resulting image file looks exactly how I want, the blacks are black and the whites are white. I do not believe my problem is with my pdf viewer, I've opened the pdf in a few different programs (Adobe Acrobat, Google Chrome, GIMP) and the pdf looks the same in all of them. I'm relatively certain plt.imsave is actually just writing the whites as grays.

I tried fixing the problem by explicitly declaring the min and max values like this:

```
plt.imsave('output.pdf', myImg, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

but it didn't change the output at all. I can say that this code was working fine before I reinstalled python on my system, but I don't know why reinstallation would make this function act differently or how I can fix it.